# IntelliJ debugger triggers break point only once until restart the application

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

My `IntelliJ Idea` triggers the breakpoints only once and in case I want to trigger same breakpoints again (ex: calling the same REST endpoint multiple times) it just ignores the breakpoints until I restart the application.

After restarting it works, but again only once and breakpoints are being ignored in subsequent calls.

This is really confusing, I tried to search on the internet and on IntelliJ website but no luck. I tried on multiple java application, the issue is same everywhere.

Below are my IDE details:
[image]

**Updated:**
breakpoint screenshot:

[image]

Updated to latest IntelliJ Idea:
[image]

OS Version:
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of your breakpoints dialog (Ctrl + Shift + F8 /  Shift+⌘+F8)

Comment: Could you update IDEA to the latest version to see if the problem is gone there?

Comment: @MartinvanWingerden updated in the description.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko just updated to latest version, still same.

Comment: Your screenshot misses the color of the bullet and you did not show the dialog I requested, I mean https://imgur.com/YaLyTmg

Comment: @MartinvanWingerden sorry, my bad. Updated (https://i.imgur.com/bKysnS6.png).

Comment: @ManinGreen two more ideas, could you share a screenshot of https://imgur.com/gb8rQtx when its non-functional. And did you try to add logging/system.out's to the endpoint to make sure its still being called and that its not a caching issue.

Comment: @MartinvanWingerden here is the screenshot you asked https://imgur.com/a/fU6frSK. Yes, as I said, debuggers hit the breakpoint when I call this /user endpoint for the first time after the application is started. However, if I call /user again (call runs successfully and I get a response as well), the same breakpoint is being ignored until I restart the app.

Comment: this is really strange issue, it's happening in all my JAVA applications. The one I shared is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current version of IntelliJ Idea:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.3 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-223.8836.41, built on March 10, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+1-b653.34 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 13.4
Kotlin: 223-1.8.0-release-345-IJ8836.41
```

For you to hit the breakpoint as many time as you want, you would have to click on **Resume Program Execution** after your debug session.

[image: Resume Program Execution]

If you click on **Run to where caret is**, the debugger won't be able to re-hit the breakpoint again until you restart your server or application.

[image]

Hope this help